# Trying to speed up some code I wrote: python

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing

So I wrote the following code, to yield pairs of partitions that yield characteristics that are useful to me, and I'm in the process of attempting to parallelize a program that stems from the output of these.

Note: r and n are nearly arbitrary, but they tend to range from 2 to 16.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def conjugate(p1):
    p = list(p1)
    if p == []:
        return p1
    else:
        l = len(p)
        conj =  [l]*p[-1]
        for i in xrange(l-1,0,-1):
            conj.extend([i]*(p[i-1] - p[i]))
        return conj

def dominates(p1,p2):
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    min_length = min(len(p1), len(p2))
    if min_length == 0:
        return len(p1) >= len(p2)

    for i in range(min_length):
        sum1 += p1[i]
        sum2 += p2[i]
        if sum2 > sum1:
            return False
    return bool(sum(p1) >= sum(p2))


def partition_lists(r,n):
    half = n*r/2
    combDict = {}
    for a in range(half,n*r+1):
        combDict[a] = []
    for a in combinations_with_replacement(range(0,n+1),r):
        if sum(a) >= half:
            combDict[sum(a)].append(list(reversed(a)))
    for key,item in combDict.iteritems():
        for i in range(len(item)):
            for j in range(len(item)):
                rp = [2*n - 2*a for a in item[i]]
                cp = [2*n - 2*a for a in item[j]]
                rpN = filter(lambda a: a != 0, reversed(rp))
                cpN = filter(lambda a: a != 0, reversed(cp))
                if dominates(conjugate(rpN),cpN):
                    yield item[i],item[j]
```

The first two functions are solid, but are used in the last one.
The last function generates row and column sums of what I am calling a "heavy" matrix, and based on these values, I calculate row and column sums for a "light" matrix (rp,cp), and then test dominance to see if a light matrix is feasible, where a light matrix is just 0s, and 1s, of half the weight of the heavy matrix.
The problem is that I generate a lot of data and through out around half of it when I get down to the dominating and conjugating functions. Is there a way to somehow get this done faster, or cut out unnecessary data sooner? 
Also is there a way to parallelize another function that will run more processes on the output from partition_lists?

Comment: Could you explain the context in which you're using this code? What is a heavy and light matrix. What exactly are you trying to do with them? What field is this? It's possible with more context we can help.